# How to replace '\\' with '\' without raising an EOL error?

Tags: python, string, encoding, readline, decoding

I am reading from a file that contains byte data but when I open the file and store the readline data into a variable it stores it in a string with backslash escapes, So when trying to decode that data I am getting the exact string data and not actually decoding.

File Example:

```
b'\xe0\xa8\xaa\xe0\xa9\xb0\xe0\xa8\x9c\xe0\xa8\xbe\xe0\xa8\xac\xe0\xa9\x80'
b'\xd9\xbe\xd9\x86\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8\xdb\x8c'
b'\xd9\xbe\xda\x9a\xd8\xaa\xd9\x88'
```

`readline` returns:

```
"b'\\xe0\\xa8\\xaa\\xe0\\xa9\\xb0\\xe0\\xa8\\x9c\\xe0\\xa8\\xbe\\xe0\\xa8\\xac\\xe0\\xa9\\x80'"
```

I get why there is an extra backslash, but I don't know how to remove it or read the file without it.

I have tried to replace those double backslashes but that raises an EOL error.

Comment: what's you desired output?

Comment: @nikeros I want to .decode the each byte line from the file and get the utf-8 data. for example- b'\xd9\xbe\xda\x9a\xd8\xaa\xd9\x88'.decode() would return 'پښتو'

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Avinash Please [edit] the question to include the desired output. As well, please add the actual output, i.e. the full error message.

Comment: Why does the file contain Python representations of `bytes` objects in the first place? Like, where is it coming from? If you're the one creating it, why not use the bytes themselves? Or you could at least use a standard serialization format like JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the string representation of a `bytes` object to an actual `bytes` object, you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> s = "b'\\xe0\\xa8\\xaa'"
>>> import ast
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> b
b'\xe0\xa8\xaa'
>>> b.decode('utf-8')
'ਪ'
```

Although, why does the file contain Python representations of `bytes` objects in the first place? Like, where is it coming from? If you're the one creating it, why not use the bytes themselves? Or you could at least use a standard serialization format like JSON.

Note that if the source of the file is untrusted and you use this approach, an attacker could crash your Python interpreter.

Comment: `s.encode('raw_unicode_escape'). decode('unicode_escape'). strip("b'"). encode('latin1'). decode()` without `ast`…

Comment: @Josef Stripping is fragile. What if `s = "b'b'"`?

Comment: D'oh! `ss = "b'barbar'"; ss.encode('raw_unicode_escape'). decode('unicode_escape'). lstrip("b"). strip("'"). encode('latin1'). decode()`?

Comment: @JosefZ What if `ss = 'b"barbar\'"'`? Anyway, why do you want to parse it yourself when you could have Python do it for you? It's so much work for no gain.

Comment: I know… An attempt to circumvent this: [Warning It is possible to **crash the Python interpreter** with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) Nothing more, nothing less…

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'rb' mode on the file, that would likely be the problem. It is still only a text file.

When I use no mode arguments I get:

```
"b'\xe0\xa8\xaa\xe0\xa9\xb0\xe0\xa8\x9c\xe0\xa8\xbe\xe0\xa8\xac\xe0\xa9\x80'
"
```

Comment: I am getting the same result as before with or without 'rb'. print() removes the extra backslashes but the variable itself doesn't store it without double backslashes.

Comment: You could try replacing the backslashes with an ANSI escape sequence

Comment: @jshwi How would an ANSI escape sequence help?